# Android opening context menu after button click

Tags: android, listview, android-contextmenu

I want to open context menu when I click a button, but also I have to know which list item is focused when I click the button. Do you know how to do that? What code should be in `onclick` method?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I was looking for the same, and found that instead of context menu, you should use Dialogs

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Comment: I've been hacking around with context menus for so long thinking they were the only solution... Thank you. This is both much easier, cleaner and visually similar to the context menu pattern

Answer (score 26):

If you really want to do it for whatever reason... (in my case, out of laziness)

During `onCreate` of your activity or somewhere before your user can touch the button, do `registerForContextMenu`on that button. Then in the actual button onClick handler, call `openContextMenu(View)`.

For example, I have a button declared in xml like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onHelp"
    android:text="@string/help_btn_text" />
```

in my onCreate

```
registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.btn_help));
```

and in onHelp function

```
public void onHelp(View v) {
    openContextMenu(v);
}
```

this works because the View v is the same as the view registered for context menu.

Answer (score 4):

First thing, you should register the view by calling **registerForContextMenu(View view)**. Second, override the **onCreateContextMenu()** to add the menus and lastly, override the **onContextItemSelected()** to put logic on each menu.

Comment: case context_menu:
this.registerForContextMenu(getListView().getFocusedChild()); this.openContextMenu(getListView().getFocusedChild());
return true;
This does not work for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know why you should use `ContextMenu`. The functionality of `ContextMenu` of a View is similar to the right-click menu on a PC, which means the "available operations" on some item.

According to your description, I think what you actually need is a **customized Dialog with a list**, which is displayed when clicking the Button and is also able to get the focused item of your `ListView`. Then you can save the registration of `ContextMenu` for some View that really needs the menu:)

Comment: Actually in my file manager application there is no scenerio that the user can handle long click. So that s why i m trying to do a button in options menu which handle the context menu. In my code i override the onCreateContextMenu() and onContextItemSelected() methods. and in my onOptionsItemSlelected method i have trying to call context menu. i tried  
case context_menu:
this.registerForContextMenu(getListView().getFocusedChild()); this.openContextMenu(getListView().getFocusedChild());
return true;
This does not work for me. Any idea?