# Context menu for a button using android?

Tags: android, view, android-contextmenu

I have a button that when pressed, will call the company. Now, I was doing some research and found that there is a way to include a context menu. I really like the context menu because it gives you so many options.

Do you think it would be a waste of code to set a context menu for a click of the button that when pressed will open up the options to add contact, call contact, sms contact, etc.? Is it necessary?

I did come across these:
[Android opening context menu after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645235/android-opening-context-menu-after-button-click)
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html#tour_of_the_menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a good feature to include. Thats what context menu is there for, to give more options. I think it would be good to give the user more options when the button is clicked. Well it makes more since anyway.

Heres how you would get the long click

```
Button downSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downSelected);
    downSelected.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
});
```

EDIT:

If you just want one click on the button just register its click listener like this..

```
downSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Hmm. thank you for your input. Is there any documentation or advice you can help me start getting on the ball? thanks. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions

Comment: As far making a context menu? Sure.. Perfect guide here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Okay, I just added that code to my app and it only brings up the longclicklistener...is there a way to have both methods? one click will bring up the call and the long click will bring up the context?

Comment: callUs.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String phoneNumber = "tel:+1800-210-9821";
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
   startActivity(callIntent);
   return true;
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to provide a big main button to call the number, and some additional mechanism, let's say a smaller + button to do more stuff with as you sugggested. Also a long click could be considered a right user interaction to provide with more features.

Just a user feeling...

Comment: How would one set up a long click thing? I am really new to Java so everything is new...I'm jumping in head first!

Comment: I show you how to set up the long click listener in my answer =)