# How to get the position of the Item clicked on ContextMenu?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, contextmenu

I am using this code to get the Clicked Item position on the Context Menu:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
}
```

as suggested here:

[Android: How to find the position clicked from the context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453620/android-how-to-find-the-position-clicked-from-the-context-menu#answers-header)

But i get NullPointerException at line:

```
 int index = info.position;
```

why is it so?

**EDIT**

I have 2 registered Views for the contextMenu like this:

```
button1.onClick(view v){
registerForContextMenu(v);
openContextMenu(v);
}

button2.onClick(view v){
registerForContextMenu(v);
openContextMenu(v);
}
```

then depending on v.getId() i populate the menu.

Comment: might be you dont have any item in your menu array.

Comment: Did you register your context menu?

Comment: I definitely have items. and regarding registration, yeah i am doing, but then soon i am unregistered, for some reason. so thats the problem??

Comment: But i removed unregister line. It still gives the same error

Comment: [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3729992/1398150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use directly:

**EDITED BEGIN**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // If the menu object can't be cast, logs an error.
        Log.e("MENU", "bad menuInfo", e);
        return;
    }
    position = sectionAdapter.getIndexForPosition(info.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("");
    String[] menuItems = { "item1","item2","item3","item4" };
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
    }
}
```

**EDITED END**

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int position = item.getItemId();
    switch (position) 
    {

        case 0:
        break;
        .
        .
        .
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: getItemId() returns the position??are you sure?

Comment: yes i have used it...it will give you position of the context menu's item

Comment: Its giving value 0 for every item i clicked. What might be wrong??

Comment: Have you register context menu using registerContextMenu()...?

Comment: i am checking the value of info just after this step: "info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;" it gives null

Comment: I tried your edited code. there is no exception, but then i get null for info in the try block

Comment: for me it works perfectly this same code. now try by removing your code "openContextMenu(v);" line in edit section.

Comment: 1 thing. should i register just after getting the view from the resource. because what i am doing in my code is. on this view clicked i register and open the contextmenu

Comment: then do one thing try without registering the context menu and also refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645235/android-opening-context-menu-after-button-click)

Comment: i am getting item name correctly if i am using item.toString(). But item id i am getting 0 for all of them and item.getMenuInfo() gives null

Comment: yeah, even i might end up using dialogs, but i just want to know the reason i get this issue

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/